# Sending packet or Stream of bytes directly to USB HID Device

Tags: usb, packets

Is it possible to send packet information directly to a HId Device connected to my PC from my VB.Net application?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a library like this one: http://www.nuget.org/packages/hidlibrary/

Comment: Rick this library look great! I am trying to send information to the kinect sensor to change the LED colour. So far I am successful by using a python script compiles to executable and then calling it from my .net code.

Blah! Not the best!

Would you be interesting in possibly helping me understand some of the important parts of the library you recommended?

Comment: Well unfortunately, as good as this library is. The kinect sensor didn't appear in an enumerated list if USB devices.